# Merge a new interval into given array of intervals

Tags: python, programming-challenge, interval

This is Merge Intervals problem from [www.interviewbit.com](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/merge-intervals/?ref=dash-reco)

> **Problem** : Given a set of non-overlapping intervals, insert a new interval into the intervals (merge if necessary). You may assume that
>   the intervals were initially sorted according to their start times.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> Given intervals [1,3],[6,9] insert and merge [2,5] :
> result [1,5],[6,9].
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> Given intervals [1,2],[3,5],[6,7],[8,10],[12,16], insert and merge [4,9]
> result in [1,2],[3,10],[12,16]
> ```

**My Approach**:

```
def insert( intervals, new_interval):
    """returns list of intervals after merging"""
    count = 0
    status = False
    final_interval = []
    k = len(intervals)
    new_interval =  (min(new_interval),max(new_interval))
    for i in range(k):

        ## if new interval lesser than given interval
        if min(new_interval) < min(intervals[i]) and max(new_interval) < min(intervals[i]):
            status = False
            break 

        ## if new interval falls under given interval
        elif min(new_interval) >= min(intervals[i]) and max(new_interval)<= max(intervals[i]):
            status = True
            break 

        ## if given interval falls under new interval    
        elif min(new_interval) <= min(intervals[i]) and max(new_interval)>= max(intervals[i]):
            intervals.remove(intervals[i])
            status = True
            intervals.insert(i, new_interval)


        ## part of new interval overlaps with left part of given interval
        elif min(new_interval) <= max(intervals[i]) and min(new_interval) >= min(intervals[i]):
            intervals[i][1]  = max(new_interval)
            new_interval = intervals[i] 
            status = True

        ## part of new interval overlaps with right part of given interval
        elif max(new_interval) > min(intervals[i])and max(new_interval) <= max(intervals[i]):

            new_interval[1]  = max(intervals[i])
            intervals.remove(intervals[i])
            status = True
            intervals.insert(i, new_interval)
        count+= 1               
    if not status:
        intervals.insert(count,new_interval)

    for elem in intervals:
        if elem not in final_interval:
            final_interval.append(elem)

    return final_interval
```

Test Cases:

```
print insert([[1,2],[3,6]],[8,10])
print insert([[3,5],[7,9]],[1,10])
print insert([[3,6],[8,10]],[1,2])
print insert([[1,2],[8,10]],[3,6])
print insert([[1,2],[3,5],[6,7],[8,10],[12,16]],[4,9])
print insert([[1,3],[6,9]],[2,5])
```

How can this problem be solved in a better way?

Comment: You're running Python 2. What version are they running?

Comment: @ Mast they are also using Python 2

Comment: does the code you have posted here, work on the website you coded it for?

Comment: @Malachi yes the code posted here works on the website after i made changes in the type of  received inputs and returned output,since this code was defined in a class which was subclass of another class interval. But here no need to change cause i want to optimise the function or the logic used, no class defined here .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid indexing repetitively. You know that you'll want `intervals[i]` frequently within the loop, so index it once... or better yet, loop on it efficiently in the first place:

```
for i, (low, high) in enumerate(intervals):
    if new_interval[0] < low and new_interval[1] < low:
        # ...
```

Along the same lines, you frequently want the know the min and max of the new interval; you already compute these values, why keep it as a tuple that has to be indexed again and again?

```
new_low, new_high = min(new_interval), max(new_interval)
# ...
for i, (low, high) in enumerate(intervals):
    if new_low < low and new_high < low:
        # ...
```

---

Use `my_list.pop(i)` instead of `my_list.remove(my_list[i])`. The first requires Python to iterate through the list element by element, check for equality against `my_list[i]`, and remove the first equal element it finds; the second tells it exactly what part of the list you want gone much more efficiently, since you already know the location `i`.

Better yet, use an approach that doesn't modify `intervals` at all (no popping or inserting). It's entirely possible to solve this problem by only appending new outputs to `final_interval` with no other list mutations. That's particularly important if you're iterating on `intervals`, in which case mutating it within the `for` loop will break your code.

---

Your final loop is `O(N^2)`, which is not necessary for this problem:

```
for elem in intervals:  # O(n)
    if elem not in final_interval:  # O(n)
        final_interval.append(elem)
```

Since you know that the values in `intervals` are sorted already, I would instead suggest an approach that stops the first loop after you've output `new_interval` and all intervals it overlaps with, then the second loop just pumps out the remaining items from where the first loop left off.

---

And now to actually answer your specific error: you've defined your function to work on a list of lists (or tuples, whatever), and return the same; the actual problem hosted on the site provides a list of Interval objects and expects a list of Interval objects back. This is easy to support:

```
def insert(self, intervals, new_interval):
    intervals = [(v.start, v.end) for v in intervals]
    new_interval = (new_interval.start, new_interval.end)
    new_low, new_high = min(*new_interval), max(*new_interval)
    # ...
    return [Interval(l, h) for l, h in final_interval]
```

Comment: @scenerd thanks for review and pointing out the mistake